# OpenTok - cycling camera/ switch camera to front/back on mobile device in video call

Tags: web, opentok, tokbox

I have a problem with switching between front and back camera when streaming with OpenTok (Web version but in mobile browser). can any one help me out for this?

I was trying to switch camera using below code line. but it doesn't work.

```
publisher.cycleVideo();
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are using a version of chrome that is too old to support replaceTrack. The `cycleVideo` method returns a promise, you should handle it and see if you get an error message. That will give you more details.

`publisher.cycleVideo().catch(console.error);`